# JS form fill limit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to release the textarea/input where user can write only numbers **BUT** till 24?

Like 1,2,3,...,24.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQuery is best.

http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation